# Fixed position to show on some sections but hidden on home

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if someone could give me a solution.

I have a website that scrolls horizontally. I divided it in six sections being the first section the home page. This home page features a navigation system different to the rest of sections for which I used a standard horizontal nav bar.

My problem is that I need the nav bar to stay fixed on its position so when I scroll down, it's still there but I don't want this nav bar to show on the home screen. Is there anyway I can have the nav bar fixed on different sections of the site while is hidden on the homepage?

Any help will be much appreciated. I attach the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zpeua/

Many thanks guys!

Gon

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="mask">
    <div id="item1" class="item">
        <div id="Header" class="effect2">
            <div id="Logo"></div>
            <div id="ContactDetails"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav" class="Home">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">Repertoire</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  <a name="item1"></a>

        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">
        <div id="nav" class="Home">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">Repertoire</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  <a name="item2"></a>

        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item3" class="item">
        <div id="nav" class="Home">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">Repertoire</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  <a name="item3"></a>

        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item4" class="item">
        <div id="nav" class="Home">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">Repertoire</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  <a name="item4"></a>

        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item5" class="item">
        <div id="nav" class="Home">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">Repertoire</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  <a name="item5"></a>

        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item6" class="item">
        <div id="nav" class="Home">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">Repertoire</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  <a name="item6"></a>

        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:33px 0;
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    overflow:auto;
}
#nav {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:127px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#FFF;
    z-index:999;
    padding-top:7px;
}
#nav ul {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1015px;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    margin:0 60px 0 60px;
}
#nav li a {
    color:#999;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
#mask {
    width:600%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.item {
    width:16.6%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    float:left;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:165px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
.selected {
    background:#fff;
    font-weight:700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    current = $(this);

    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);

    return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});

});

function resizePanel() {

width = $(window).width();
height = $(window).height();

mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

$('#debug').html(width + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

$('#wrapper, .item').css({
    width: width,
    height: height
});
$('#mask').css({
    width: mask_width,
    height: height
});
$('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}

;(function( $ ){

var $scrollTo = $.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
    $(window).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
};

$scrollTo.defaults = {
    axis:'xy',
    duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1
};

// Returns the element that needs to be animated to scroll the window.
// Kept for backwards compatibility (specially for localScroll & serialScroll)
$scrollTo.window = function( scope ){
    return $(window)._scrollable();
};

// Hack, hack, hack :)
// Returns the real elements to scroll (supports window/iframes, documents and regular nodes)
$.fn._scrollable = function(){
    return this.map(function(){
        var elem = this,
            isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;

            if( !isWin )
                return elem;

        var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

        return $.browser.safari || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
            doc.body : 
            doc.documentElement;
    });
};

$.fn.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
    if( typeof duration == 'object' ){
        settings = duration;
        duration = 0;
    }
    if( typeof settings == 'function' )
        settings = { onAfter:settings };

    if( target == 'max' )
        target = 9e9;

    settings = $.extend( {}, $scrollTo.defaults, settings );
    // Speed is still recognized for backwards compatibility
    duration = duration || settings.speed || settings.duration;
    // Make sure the settings are given right
    settings.queue = settings.queue && settings.axis.length > 1;

    if( settings.queue )
        // Let's keep the overall duration
        duration /= 2;
    settings.offset = both( settings.offset );
    settings.over = both( settings.over );

    return this._scrollable().each(function(){
        var elem = this,
            $elem = $(elem),
            targ = target, toff, attr = {},
            win = $elem.is('html,body');

        switch( typeof targ ){
            // A number will pass the regex
            case 'number':
            case 'string':
                if( /^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ) ){
                    targ = both( targ );
                    // We are done
                    break;
                }
                // Relative selector, no break!
                targ = $(targ,this);
            case 'object':
                // DOMElement / jQuery
                if( targ.is || targ.style )
                    // Get the real position of the target 
                    toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset();
        }
        $.each( settings.axis.split(''), function( i, axis ){
            var Pos = axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                pos = Pos.toLowerCase(),
                key = 'scroll' + Pos,
                old = elem[key],
                max = $scrollTo.max(elem, axis);

            if( toff ){// jQuery / DOMElement
                attr[key] = toff[pos] + ( win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos] );

                // If it's a dom element, reduce the margin
                if( settings.margin ){
                    attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin'+Pos)) || 0;
                    attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border'+Pos+'Width')) || 0;
                }

                attr[key] += settings.offset[pos] || 0;

                if( settings.over[pos] )
                    // Scroll to a fraction of its width/height
                    attr[key] += targ[axis=='x'?'width':'height']() * settings.over[pos];
            }else{ 
                var val = targ[pos];
                // Handle percentage values
                attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ? 
                    parseFloat(val) / 100 * max
                    : val;
            }

            // Number or 'number'
            if( /^\d+$/.test(attr[key]) )
                // Check the limits
                attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min( attr[key], max );

            // Queueing axes
            if( !i && settings.queue ){
                // Don't waste time animating, if there's no need.
                if( old != attr[key] )
                    // Intermediate animation
                    animate( settings.onAfterFirst );
                // Don't animate this axis again in the next iteration.
                delete attr[key];
            }
        });

        animate( settings.onAfter );            

        function animate( callback ){
            $elem.animate( attr, duration, settings.easing, callback && function(){
                callback.call(this, target, settings);
            });
        };

    }).end();
};

// Max scrolling position, works on quirks mode
// It only fails (not too badly) on IE, quirks mode.
$scrollTo.max = function( elem, axis ){
    var Dim = axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
        scroll = 'scroll'+Dim;

    if( !$(elem).is('html,body') )
        return elem[scroll] - $(elem)[Dim.toLowerCase()]();

    var size = 'client' + Dim,
        html = elem.ownerDocument.documentElement,
        body = elem.ownerDocument.body;

    return Math.max( html[scroll], body[scroll] ) 
         - Math.min( html[size]  , body[size]   );

};

function both( val ){
    return typeof val == 'object' ? val : { top:val, left:val };
};

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Place your navbar with `position: fixed`?

Comment: Tried that but when I do it, it does show in the home screen.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to achieve... can you clarify?

Comment: Right. What I need is the nav bar to show on every section except on the home screen. Within these other sections (not the home section) where the nav bar shows, it has to be fixed so it doesn't disappear when you scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix the header to the top of the page and use jQuery to detect what page you're on within $(document).ready() and hide the header when you are on the home page.  So within your $('a.panel').click() you'll just need this:

`if($(this).html() == 'Home' && !$('#HomeNavId').is(':visible'))
{
    $('#HomeNavId').show();
} else {
    $('#HomeNavId').hide();
}`

Comment: The header is already fixed. Could I use jQuery to detect what #item I am in and hide just the nav? If so, that's what I was looking for!! :)

Comment: Exactly, I'd put id's on your items instead of relying on the href attribute.  In my example where I use $(this).html() you can replace it with $(this).attr('href') or $(this).id if you put id attributes on them.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time dude. I really appreciate it. Considering is only on the home screen where I want the nav hidden, would this be correct?

if($(this).attr('#item1')  == 'Home' && !$('#nav').is(':hidden'))
{
    $('#nav').show();
} else {
    $('#nav.Home').hide();
}

Comment: Your first check in your if is wrong.  It should be either $(this).attr('href') == 'item1' or you can check the html with $(this).html() == 'Home'